# strings contarting '<cr>' should appear at last while sorting

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, qsort

I have the following set of strings

```
'aa'
'hello'
'start'
'<1-10>'
'<cr>'
```

When i use qsort from the sort library in C, I get the following output

```
<1-10>
<cr>
aa
hello
start
```

But I want the following output

```
<1-10>
aa
hello
start
<cr>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please show your code. We are not mind readers and cannot tell you what is wrong with it without seeing it. And please use only the relevant language tag - C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: C or C++? And which data structure do you want to use for the string list/array/raw pointer array/vector/...?

Comment: C, I'm using vector

Comment: @deathstroke05: Considering that `std::vector` is a C++-only type, we're pretty sure that you're not using C.

Comment: C++ tag removed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Move strings containing `<cr>` into a different container.
2. Sort the rest of the strings.
3. Sort the containers holding the strings containing `<cr>`
4. Add the second containers items at the end of first list

Moreover, instead of using separate containers, you can move the strings containing `<cr>` at end of the list (`std::partition`) and apply `qsort` on the two subarrays differently.

```
bool partitioner(string str) {
    return str.find("<cr>") == string::npos;
}
```

And now:

```
vector<string> v {"hello", "world", "<cr>", "<cr>string"};
auto bound = partition(v.begin(), v.end(), partitioner);
sort(v.begin(), bound);
sort(bound, v.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your actual setting, because `vector` is a C++ type, whereas you state that you want to use C.
Anyway, maybe the following code written for std::vector in combination with std::sort shows the basic principle, where you introduce a custom comparison function for sorting. Note that `qsort` allows custom comparison functions, too, yet the syntax will be different.

The custom comparison function works as follows: if both strings start with `<`, then their remainders are compared. If one of them starts with `<`, then this one is always ranked below the other. Otherwise, they are simply compared. I used `char*`-data type to keep up some flavour of C for you :-) :

```
int main() {

    std::vector<const char*> s = {
        "aa",
        "start",
        "hello",
        "<d-10>",
        "<cr>"
    };

    // sort using a custom function object
    struct {
        bool operator()(const char*a, const char*b)
        {
            if (*a == '<') {
                if (*b == '<') {
                    return strcmp(a+1,b+1) < 0;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (*b == '<') {
                if (*a == '<') {
                    return strcmp(a+1,b+1) < 0;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
                return strcmp(a,b) < 0;
        }
    } customLess;

    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), customLess);
    for (auto a : s) {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
aa
hello
start
<cr>
<d-10>
```